# Only one value is not inserting into my MYSQL db?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am totally new to this field. I am trying to implement Google OAuth to pull the data, but unfortunately, I can't insert my username value into my MySQL database. Other statements are working fine and inserting properly, but the one  that should insert username is not working as expected. I've spent almost 4 hours attempting to fix it. I don't know what to do.

**index.php**

```
    <?php ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE); ?>


    <?php 

    include_once("config.php");
    include_once("includes/functions.php");

    //print_r($_GET);die;

    if(isset($_REQUEST['code'])){
      $gClient->authenticate();
      $_SESSION['token'] = $gClient->getAccessToken();
      header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
    }

    if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
      $gClient->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
    }



    if ($gClient->getAccessToken()) {
      $userProfile = $google_oauthV2->userinfo->get();
      //DB Insert
      //$gUser->setApprovalPrompt ("auto");

      $gUser = new Users();
      // As of PHP 5.3.0

      $gUser->checkUser('google',$userProfile['id'],$userProfile['given_name'],$userProfile['family_name'],$userProfile['email'],$userProfile['gender'],$userProfile['locale'],$userProfile['link'],$userProfile['picture'],$username);
      $_SESSION['google_data'] = $userProfile; // Storing Google User Data in Session
      header("location: feed.php");

      $_SESSION['token'] = $gClient->getAccessToken();
    } else {
      $authUrl = $gClient->createAuthUrl();
    }

      $email  = $_SESSION['google_data']['email'];
      $user = strstr($email, '@', true);
      $username = $user; 
?>
```

**functions.php**

```
<?php ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE); ?>

<?php
 session_start();
class Users {
    public $tableName = 'users';

 function __construct(){
        //database configuration
        $dbServer = 'localhost'; //Define database server host
        $dbUsername = 'root'; //Define database username
        $dbPassword = ''; //Define database password
        $dbName = 'livelor'; //Define database name

        //connect databse
        $con = mysqli_connect($dbServer,$dbUsername,$dbPassword,$dbName);
        if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
            die("Failed to connect with MySQL: ".mysqli_connect_error());
        }else{
            $this->connect = $con;
        }
    }

    function checkUser($oauth_provider,$oauth_uid,$fname,$lname,$email,$gender,$locale,$link,$picture,$username){
        $prevQuery = mysqli_query($this->connect,"SELECT * FROM $this->tableName WHERE oauth_provider = '".$oauth_provider."' AND oauth_uid = '".$oauth_uid."'") or die(mysqli_error($this->connect));
        if(mysqli_num_rows($prevQuery) > 0){
            $update = mysqli_query($this->connect,"UPDATE $this->tableName SET oauth_provider = '".$oauth_provider."', oauth_uid = '".$oauth_uid."' ,fname = '".$fname."', lname = '".$lname."', email = '".$email."', gender = '".$gender."', locale = '".$locale."', picture = '".$picture."', gpluslink = '".$link."', modified = '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."' WHERE oauth_provider = '".$oauth_provider."' AND oauth_uid = '".$oauth_uid."'") or die(mysqli_error($this->connect));
        }else{
            $insert = mysqli_query($this->connect,"INSERT INTO $this->tableName SET oauth_provider = '".$oauth_provider."', oauth_uid = '".$oauth_uid."', fname = '".$fname."', lname = '".$lname."', email = '".$email."', gender = '".$gender."', locale = '".$locale."', picture = '".$picture."', gpluslink = '".$link."', created = '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."', modified = '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."' ,  username='".$username."' ") or die(mysqli_error($this->connect));
        }

        $query = mysqli_query($this->connect,"SELECT * FROM $this->tableName WHERE oauth_provider = '".$oauth_provider."' AND oauth_uid = '".$oauth_uid."'") or die(mysqli_error($this->connect));
        $result = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
        return $result;

    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you set `$username`? You're passing it into `checkUser` as a parameter, but there's nothing actually setting it.

Comment: `checkUser('google',$userProfile['id'],$userProfile['given_name'],$userProfile['family_name'],$userProfile['email'],$userProfile['gender'],$userProfile['locale'],$userProfile['link'],$userProfile['picture'],$username);` Just check the last variable .And there is also an algoritm to split the username from email.That is in last few lines of code in index.php @andrewsi

Comment: define this `$user = strstr($email, '@', true);
      $username = $user; ` before your function call

Comment: You only set $username to $user AFTER the call the checkUser that does the insert

Comment: @Bajwakapoor - no. You're _using_ `$username` there, but you've not yet given it a value.

Comment: No luck for me @Saty its not working

Comment: `$email  = $_SESSION['google_data']['email'];
      $user = strstr($email, '@', true);
      $username = $user;` @andrewsi

Comment: @Bajwakapoor - which is called _after you call the function_. I'm not sure how many times I can say this.... You need to set `$username` _before you call the function_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this line:-

```
$gUser->checkUser('google',$userProfile['id'],$userProfile['given_name'],$userProfile['family_name'],$userProfile['email'],$userProfile['gender'],$userProfile['locale'],$userProfile['link'],$userProfile['picture'],$username);
```

to this:-

```
$gUser->checkUser('google',$userProfile['id'],$userProfile['given_name'],$userProfile['family_name'],$userProfile['email'],$userProfile['gender'],$userProfile['locale'],$userProfile['link'],$userProfile['picture'],strstr($userProfile['email'], '@', true));
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two major issues in your code. First, you use the invalid SQL syntaxis. It's `INSERT INTO table(column) VALUES(value)`, not `SET`. And as far as I see it, your `$username` is not defined. You are trying to insert `$username`, which is passed into the function:

```
function checkUser($oauth_provider,$oauth_uid,$fname,$lname,$email,$gender,$locale,$link,$picture,$username){
// other code
$insert = mysqli_query($this->connect,"INSERT INTO $this->tableName ( oauth_provider, oauth_uid, fname, lname, email, gender, locale, picture, gpluslink, created, modified,  username) VALUES( '".$oauth_provider."', '".$oauth_uid."', '".$fname."', '".$lname."', '".$email."', '".$gender."', '".$locale."', '".$picture."', '".$link."', '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."', '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."' ,  '".$username."')") or die(mysqli_error($this->connect));
// etc
}
```

Tracing the function call to

```
$gUser->checkUser('google',$userProfile['id'],$userProfile['given_name'],$userProfile['family_name'],$userProfile['email'],$userProfile['gender'],$userProfile['locale'],$userProfile['link'],$userProfile['picture'],$username);
```

Passing an empty `$username` variable as a parameter into a function **IS NOT DEFINING IT**.

And I just don't see `$username` to be defined anywhere prior to that.

I hope this doesn't sound very sarcastic, but in order to set `$username` right you have to either define `$username` prior to your function call or pass the setting string into the function.

```
$username = 'banana';
$gUser->checkUser('google',$userProfile['id'],$userProfile['given_name'],$userProfile['family_name'],$userProfile['email'],$userProfile['gender'],$userProfile['locale'],$userProfile['link'],$userProfile['picture'],$username);
```

OR

```
$gUser->checkUser('google',$userProfile['id'],$userProfile['given_name'],$userProfile['family_name'],$userProfile['email'],$userProfile['gender'],$userProfile['locale'],$userProfile['link'],$userProfile['picture'],'banana');
```

Comment: See the last variable that defines `$gUser->checkUser('google',$userProfile['id'],$userProfile['given_name'],$userProfile['family_name'],$userProfile['email'],$userProfile['gender'],$userProfile['locale'],$userProfile['link'],$userProfile['picture'],$username);`

Comment: @Bajwakapoor this is **_NOT_** defining, it's passing the **empty** variable as a parameter to a function

Comment: OK just tell me what do to ?

Comment: You have to either set `$username` prior to fucntion call, or pass a string containing username to the function... But I suggest you read PHP manual on basics - how variables work, how they are passed etc. You clearly do not understand those basics (no offense)

Comment: As i said before I am very new to PHP .But Last step you told is working 'banana'

Answer (score 0):

Your insert sql is wrong - check the correct syntax:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1,column2,column3,...)
VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);
```

Comment: But How the other data's are inserting correctly expect username @Adidi

Comment: The manual says INSERT ... SET should work: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html

Comment: well i don't see you `$username` is defined anywhere is the code - where do you define it ?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there is a SET alternative syntax for INSERT INTO for MySQL. Who knew.

Okay, so the issue is here:

```
--This will return false, $username is not set
echo isset($username);

$gUser->checkUser('google',$userProfile['id'],$userProfile['given_name'],
$userProfile['family_name'],$userProfile['email'],$userProfile['gender'],
$userProfile['locale'],$userProfile['link'],$userProfile['picture'],$username);
$_SESSION['google_data'] = $userProfile; // Storing Google User Data in Session
header("location: feed.php");

$_SESSION['token'] = $gClient->getAccessToken();
} else {
$authUrl = $gClient->createAuthUrl();
}

$email  = $_SESSION['google_data']['email'];
$user = strstr($email, '@', true);
$username = $user;
```

You are trying to use the $username variable before you assign it. What you need to do is:

```
$email  = $_SESSION['google_data']['email'];
$user = strstr($email, '@', true);
$username = $user; 

--This will return true, $username is set
echo isset($username);

$gUser->checkUser('google',$userProfile['id'],$userProfile['given_name'],
$userProfile['family_name'],$userProfile['email'],$userProfile['gender'],
$userProfile['locale'],$userProfile['link'],$userProfile['picture'],$username);
$_SESSION['google_data'] = $userProfile; // Storing Google User Data in Session
header("location: feed.php");

$_SESSION['token'] = $gClient->getAccessToken();
} else {
$authUrl = $gClient->createAuthUrl();
}
```